# How to center image vertically in thumbnail in shopping cart

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In the shopping, cart images need to center vertically in thumbnails.

I tried html

```
<a class="productselect-image" href="/Details/131631?lang=et">
   <img src="/Image/Product?product=131631&amp;size=228">
</a>
```

CSS:

```
.productselect-image {
    height: 260px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.productselect-image img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

But the image will appear at the bottom. How to center in vertically as pointed by reading arro[image]w:

short images appear in bottom and cart looks ugly. How to make it nicer?

Bootstrap 3 and ASP.NET MVC4 are used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.productselect-image{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

How about using `display:flex`?

**It's my output**

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It works if `height: 260px` is used. Without adding height images have variable height. How to avoid hard-coded height so that all images will have same height? Pictures are always returned  to fit into square of 228px height and width. For non-square images narrower side will be less than 228px and only way to fix it seemas to use hard-coded height. Can hard-coded height avoided?

Comment: @Andrus check my answer for another fix for your images.

Comment: Thank you. Can hard coded heights removed from your answer ? Can css create all thumbnails with tallest thumbnail height automatically ?

Comment: @Andrus with my answer no, with this answer no. That is a new question by it's own.  Do your product cards have a fixed height, or do you want them to?

Comment: Customer wants that all cards have same height. I'm using hard coded value 260px currently but looking for a way to remove it. Is some customer sites product names are  short. 260px leaves ugly space then. Other customers use long product names and 260px height allows 3 lines for product names for them. I'm looking for a wat so that height is determined automatically, exact value is not so important but all cards in same page have same height.

Answer (score 1):

If you know your height you can use `line-height` to be the same as `height`, else go with `display: flex;`. Also use a `max-width` and `max-height` to keep your images in inside the `productselect-image`

```
.productselect-image {
    height: 260px;
    line-height: 260px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.productselect-image img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the image parent is already positioned relative you can just add this to the image css

```
.productselect-image img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

This is the most standard way of centering things vertically.

Answer (score -2):

try using bootstrap
the code is something like this

```
<div class="thumbnail" style="width: XXpx; height: YYpx">
<div class="thumbnail_wrapper">
    <img src="#"/>
</div>
</div>
```